# How can you capture a subset of a screenshot in iOS using Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, screenshot

How do you capture only a sub-set of the entire screen using Objective-C on an iOS device?

I found the following code:

```
UIWindow *screenWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenWindow.frame.size);
[screenWindow.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Which works great but I only want to create an image from a piece of the entire window. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crop Screen shot Programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388047/crop-screen-shot-programatically)

Comment: I think you just specify a different size in UIGraphicsBeginImageContext.  Then you can do translates to position that frame over the desired part of the view.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

replace

> UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenWindow.frame.size);

with

> UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height));

Comment: is that assuming the x and y are at (0,0)? What if I wanted to take a screen-shot of the center if the image say (50,50)?

Comment: @thiesdiggity -- That's where you do the translate thingie, if I understand correctly.  But see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/UIKitFunctionReference.pdf

Comment: please remember to accept answers if they answered your question.